# Limit Authentication to specific username in Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

Is it possible to limit authentication in Nginx to a specific username? I.e I have multiple subdomains and want to limit that subdomain to ONLY 1 user. All the users are in 1 .htpassword file. In Apache you can do it as follows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user rbowen
```

However I haven't been able to find a similar way in Nginx.

This is how my current Nginx setup is. I have one of these in each server {} block for each user.

```
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords;
```

Comment: You could create an HTTP endpoint which validates the user against the path and returns 200 or an error if it's not allowed. You then reference this endpoint with the [ngx_http_auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module.

Comment: @Marc it's not required, added the answer with the config example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question well, you have a file containing multiple user names and passwords and you want to limit the authentication to a specific user from that file for each server block and keep the configuration centralized ?

Unfortunately you can't do that with nginx, you will need to split the file into multiple ones containing only one user:password pair.

Comment: you definitely can, hopefully nginx config is not a yaml file

Answer (score 2):

Actually with some trickery it's possible:

```
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords;

    set $AUTHFAIL "";
    if ($remote_user != "rbowen") {
      set $AUTHFAIL "1";
    }
    # required, when user is not yet authorized to ... basically authorize 
    if ($remote_user = "") {
      set $AUTHFAIL "";
    }

    if ($AUTHFAIL = "1") {
      return 403;
    }
```

Here we setting a variable to be empty, if it empty we are good to go. But if authorized user not matching the pattern - the further request would fail with HTTP 403.

Also, by changing the pattern, it is possible to provide a list of the users or move the construction to the `location` block and use different users for each `location` block.

**Update:**

To make life even more easier, create file `auth_user`, at same place where `nginx.conf` are:

```
# to use:
# set $auth_user='';
# include auth_user;


auth_basic "Hey, say some magic words";
auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

set $AUTHFAIL "";
if ($remote_user != $auth_user) {
  set $AUTHFAIL "1";
}
# required, when user is not yet authorized to ... basically authorize 
if ($remote_user = "") {
  set $AUTHFAIL "";
}

if ($AUTHFAIL = "1") {
  return 403;
}
```

And then, whatever authentication is required for only particular user, use:

```
location / {
  ...
  set $auth_user='bob';
  include auth_user;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @bot dear bot, this is authored response and not copied from another site to be cited  here